# C# UdpClient server and client issue

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, udp, udpclient

**This is my server code**

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
UdpClient newsock = new UdpClient(ipep);

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");

IPEndPoint send = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

byte[] data1 = newsock.Receive(ref send);
int test1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(data1, 0);
Console.WriteLine("test1 = {0}", test1);
```

**This is my client code**

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
string stringData;
UdpClient server = new UdpClient("127.0.0.1", 9050);

IPEndPoint send = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

int test1 = 45;

byte[] data1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(test1);
server.Send(data1, data1.Length);
```

According to my client and server, 
The client is the one sending data to server.

But my requirement is other way around! and im unable to do that..
When i try adding this code to the server

```
byte[] buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello Client");
newsock.Send(buffer, buffer.Length);
```

I get an Exception as `The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets.`

Can some one help me?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check out [JoinMulticastGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fxkak8t.aspx) (it's *like* Connect for TcpClient).  You need to do this prior to broadcasting (that is, if you are broadcasting).

The documentation for [UdpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) will also be helpful to you.

Comment: Multicast is an independent concept.  A typical client-server UDP application would not use multicast.

Comment: @Ben:  Fair enough, I'm guessing the documentation for UdpClient is all the OP really needed.

Answer (score 3):

UDP is connectionless.  When you call `connect` on a UDP socket, you are really just setting the default destination IP and port.  The receiver on the other end has to use [Socket.ReceiveFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivefrom%28VS.71%29.aspx) (called `recvfrom` in UNIX) to find out where the packet came from and then `SendTo` to reply to the original request.  The server could use `connect` but that would be awkward if you wanted to support multiple clients.